# php - How to get the group name under windows?

Tags: php

I am using:

```
getmygid();
```

to get the group id, I can get the name under linux by pulling it from the getegid array. Can you do something similar with windows?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

**[Wikipedia whoami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami)**:

> In computing, whoami is a command found on most Unix-like operating
>   systems, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2003, and
>   Windows Server 2008.

Windows **[whoami](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)** command at technet.microsoft.com:

> Displays user, group and privileges information for the user who is
>   currently logged on to the local system. If used without parameters,
>   whoami displays the current domain and user name.

**[str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)** php function:

> Parses a string input for fields in CSV format and returns an array
>   containing the fields read.

Here is the code:

```
$groups_csv = shell_exec('whoami /groups /fo csv');
print_r( str_getcsv($groups_csv) );
```